# How to tell eshell to use the os-specific tools if available

Tags: eshell

I understand why `eshell` provides elisp interpretations of the `kill` and `rm` commands, however, I would like Emacs to use the operating-specific implementations if they are available in the `$PATH` (especially in the case of `rm`, because the elisp implementation of `rm` can take *minutes* to delete large directories of files).

How can I tell Emacs to use the `rm` command in `$PATH` if available, and only fall back to the elisp implementation if not found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just for a single invocation then, as per the eshell manual (look for the "[Built-in commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Built_002dins)" section), you can prefix any command with '*' to ignore the built-ins:

```
$ which ls
eshell/ls is a compiled Lisp function in `em-ls.el'
```

Compared with:

```
$ which *ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

That same page has the tip that if you wanted to always do this (say for your `rm` example), you could define a permanent alias:

```
$ alias rm '*rm $*'
$ which rm
/usr/bin/rm
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. :)

Comment: @Boccaperta-IT: then I won the karma-race! (it doesn't often happen to me!)

Answer (score 0):

*shameless plug*

This is not exactly the solution to your problem, but I think is close enough for you to consider it if a better answer doesn't show up. I wrote an extension a while back, [shell-ext](https://github.com/rlazo/shell-ext), which works with shell-mode rather than eshell, but it intercepts the commands before being executed, letting you do  whatever you want with it, like calling a different command based on OS. It relies on a hook that shell-mode provides to get the input. If eshell provides a similar hook you could use the same mechanism.