# Why does eshell prefer lisp functions even when eshell-prefer-lisp-functions is nil?

Tags: eshell

If I startup emacs 24.5.2 with `emacs -Q` and do `M-x eshell`, then run:

```
$ which rm
eshell/rm is a compiled Lisp function in `em-unix.el'
```

I get the eshell version. But if I `C-h v eshell-prefer-lisp-functions` I see the value is nil. Yet [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html) states:

> If you would prefer to use the built-in commands instead of the external commands, set eshell-prefer-lisp-functions to t.

Is this a bug? I thought the docs might be backwards so I tried setting the variable to `t`, but the behavior stays the same, I continue getting the eshell implementation rather than the version in /bin.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is with `which`. If you do `rm --version`, what do you get?

Comment: @zck I get what I would get from /bin/rm, *but* the whole reason I started investigating this is because I rm'd a large directory which caused all of emacs to freeze, indicating it's using the eshell version. I believe the eshell versions fallback to the system version when they encounter an unrecognized argument for compatibility sake, so I think the fact that it outputs the coreutils' rm version info is actually misleading, and it is using the eshell version.

Comment: Well, that's confusing. Wish I could help more.

Comment: Why not use direct command instead of relying on *prefer* settings? For example: `$ *rm filename`. Starting `*` will make `eshell` skip looking for built-in commands. This method is useful for bypassing built-in commands no matter what the *prefer* settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eshell always prefers Lisp functions. `eshell-prefer-lisp-functions` only affects the interpretation of `*rm`, not the interpretation of `rm`.

Source: the source code… From Emacs 24.3:

> ```
> (defun eshell-plain-command (command args)
>   (let* ((esym (eshell-find-alias-function command))
>     …
>     (if (and …
>              (or esym eshell-prefer-lisp-functions
>                  (not (eshell-search-path command))))
>         (eshell-lisp-command sym args)
>       (eshell-external-command command args))))
> ```

`eshell-find-alias-function` looks up a function under the `eshell/` prefix. There's similar logic in `eshell/which`.

The variable's documentation is downright misleading, and the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Built_002dins) is rather misleading too. I guess the behavior is by design (after all, why would you define an eshell function if it's not to use it?), so it's a documentation bug.

To invoke the external utility, call `/bin/rm`, or, provided that you left `eshell-prefer-lisp-functions` set to nil, call `*rm*`. If you want `rm` to always invoke the external utility, you can define an alias: `alias rm "rm $*"` (thanks [GDP2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10761/gdp2)).

Comment: This is a bug report, not an answer. Delete the response or amend it with a workable solution.

Comment: Emacs User: What are you talking about? The question is "Why does eshell prefer lisp functions even when eshell-prefer-lisp-functions is nil?" and this is 100% an answer to that question.

Comment: "The only way to make `rm` always invoke the external command is to ensure that there's no function called `eshell/rm`. (That, or of course advising or redefining some of Eshell's code.)"

That's not the only way to make `rm` invoke the external command. As documented in the manual, you could make an alias which points `rm` to `*rm` (see also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/880/10761).

Comment: @Gilles No problem.